# Does slow file IO impact networking?

Tags: linux, nginx, php, google-kubernetes-engine

We are using php7, php-fpm, nginx on gke, services communicated by clusterIP.

In php7, we found out that occasionally writing the log needed to take 1~2 seconds to complete, it usually took less than 1ms.

And there is latency between our services, when frontend service communicate to backend by clusterIP (frontend php7 curl to backend nginx), it occasionally takes 1~2 seconds, but backend nginx's access.log showing the $request_time is less than 50ms.

I don't think the internal network is so slow on gke. Are these two things connected?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm unsure what is the issue but it might be possible that you csn use memcached in the nginx conf to speed up